# How do I pass an input value to a method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, oop, validation

I'm beginning to learn OOP in Javascript and my instructor is not very good and I'm learning out of a very bad book. ([http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-The-Web-Technologies-Series/dp/0538748877/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0538748877)) However I'm doing my best to use this site and any resource possible to follow along. That said! We're going over OOP and I'm trying to make a simple object oriented form validator but I'm having a problem with passing the input value to the method inside of the object. I apologize if I got the phrasing wrong. Here's my code.

```
function validate() {
    this.isEmpty = function(value) {
        if(value == "" || value.length < 1 || value == null) {
            // testing alert
            alert(value);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And my HTML

```
    <form action="" method="get">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
```

Basically what I don't get is how I can pass the input value of the field "name" to the object? And my follow up to that would be how do I pass multiple inputs? For example if I wanted to check if "name" and another field named "email" were empty?

Can anyone shed some light on how I would go about doing this in regular JS? Am I even attempting this in the right way? I have no idea since this is my first time trying anything object oriented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first it's important to know which concepts you are trying to model when doing OO. You were speaking about a "validator" concept, but perhaps it's still not specific enough. What exactly are you validating? Think about it, a "Validator" object suggests that it's actually quite flexible and is an object that could be helpful to validate many disparate models. If this isin't what you have in mind, then be more specific. For instance, you could name your *class* `MyFormValidator` (it's just an example).

Here's a very simple example of a specific validator *class* that takes a `form` as an argument and implements a public `validate` method to trigger validation on demand. The example is very simple and not quite flexible. There's a lot of space for improvements, such as removing UI concerns (like the messages), from the validator, but I did not want to make the example too complex.

*Note: _members identifies private members. You can enforce true privacy with the module pattern and/or priviledged functions, but I prefer naming conventions.*

```
function MyFormValidator(form) {
    this.form = form;
    this._errors = [];
}

MyFormValidator.prototype = {
    constructor: MyFormValidator,

    validate: function () {
        var errors = this._errors,
            name = this._valueOf('name');

        //clear previous errors
        errors.length = 0;

        if (this._isEmpty(name)) {
            errors.push('The name is mandatory');
        }

        return !errors.length;
    },

    errors: function () { return this._errors.slice() },

    _valueOf: function (fieldName) {
        return this.form.querySelector('[name="' + fieldName + '"]').value;
    },

    _isEmpty: function (value) {
        return value == "" || value.length < 1 || value == null;
    }
};

//Setting up form validation
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
    validator = new MyFormValidator(form);

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    if (!validator.validate()) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
        alert(validator.errors());
    }
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2d5c/**

Comment: Wow this has a lot of phenomenal information. This coupled with 1.44mb's response are sure to get the ball rolling with understanding this.

Comment: @Ellenbrook Do not hesitate if you have any questions ;) Good luck! Also note that you do not always have to use an OO approach. Functionnal style can be just as efficient when used wisely and luckily, JS supports both, OO and functionnal!

Comment: The only reason I am going OO is because that is what we are doing in class right now so I wanted to try and get more familiar with it and all that I did was confuse myself even more! But you really did help clear up a lot of my questions. I think I may need to focus on some more beginner lessons and documentation prior to attempting something like this but that's okay. You helped me understand it a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

When a JavaScript function is invoked inline, "this" points to the containing DOM element.

So if you want to validate the following tag:

```
<input name="test" onblur="validate();">
```

Then your validate function can grab its container's value:

```
function validate(){
  alert(this.value); //the value of input field "test"

  //to get the name of this input:
  alert(this.name);
}
```

Personally I don't code like this because the code is sensitive to its context. Instead I use this style:

```
<input name="test" onblur="validate(this);">

function validate(d){
  alert(d.value); //value
  alert(d.name); //name
}
```

As you can see, the object is explicitly passed in, and you can see that on the call stack, "this" is placed in the  tag directly. Later if you want to use the same function from another location, you can, by manually getting the object, and pass it in:

```
<input name="test" id="test">

<button onclick="validate(document.getElementById('test'));">Validate</button>
```

Unless it's an inline callback (closure) function, I avoid using the ambiguous "this" pointer to increase code readability.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use a framework when learning javascript. After you learn javascript itself, then you should dive into frameworks, not now. So i will not tell anything about vanilla yet.

You can get values of inputs in several ways. The best is to get their value by id:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value
```

So there you have it, the value of the input assigned to *name* variable.
After that you can pass that variable to validate function and see the results.

You would also want to catch the form's submit event and do the validation before the form gets submitted. To do so:

```
var form = document.getElementsByID('form'); //you should assign id 'form' to the form element

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //do not submit the form
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value
    validate(name);
});
```

Comment: I apologize, I did not mean vanilla JS, I honestly am so new that I thought it meant regular JS without a framework. I will read your response after I edit my question to reflect that!

Comment: I am a little lost on some things. I understand what you are saying. However does this relate to OOP? I don't see how I can make "moveable code" if I have to define the name of every input? In my head, I assign "value" from my method to the name of each input and then check to see if it is empty but I can't quite grasp how I can do that with out defining each of the input  values like you previously showed. Is this just not a good example of something that I could do in OOP?

Comment: This is not OOP. This is just getting values from DOM elements. And no; moveable code does not mean 'not writing names' and 'not defining things'. Also moveable code does not mean 'OOP'. I'm sorry if i confused you but you have to get values of inputs in web apps. And to get values, you have to define something (id, name, class, etc.) to catch the element. OOP is very large topic. You can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: So I guess I am having a hard time asking what I need. I apologize if I am being annoying. But don't I have an class called Validate and inside of the that class I have a method called isEmpty that uses a parameter named "value."

What I'd ultimatly like to do is create a new instance of the class that I just created and pass form values through the method to check if they are empty, no?

Comment: You are not being annoying. This site is about asking questions. That's what we are all here for. It is not class. It is "function". And validate function should have "value" parameter so that we can send a value to that function elsewhere. And then inside the validate function, you can use that value to do validation.

Comment: I think you should read the link i gave you so that you can have a grasp about OOP and JS.

Comment: I am going to read it right now. All of the information I've gotten thus far has been from my instructor and the book linked above. :-/ Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to me!

Comment: I'm happy to be of help. Internet is the best instructor if you can use.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply done like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MsgAlert()
{          
   var value    =   document.getElementById('abc').value;
   alert(value);       
}   
</script>   

<input id="abc"></input>

<button onClick="MsgAlert();">PassValue</button>
```